# Convert RGB color value to RGBA at 0.75 alpha

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rgba

I have the following code to get the background color of an element.

```
var currentColor = $(this).css('background-color');
```

which returns something like `rgb(123,123,123)`

What I now want to do convert this to rgba and show it at 0.75 alpha

So returning something like `rgba(123,123,123,0.75)`

Any ideas?

Comment: have you considered regex?

Comment: Any reason you want to change it to rgba instead of using jQuerys $.fadeTo-function? rgba won't work in older browsers. I would do $(this).fadeTo(0, 0.75) instead.

Comment: @ninja Can you submit your comment as an answer so I can up vote it. Its a  better solution if you are already using jQuery.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since jQuery always seems to return the color like `rgb(r, g, b)` for elements that have no alpha, you could simply use:

```
$(this).css('background-color').replace(')', ', 0.75)').replace('rgb', 'rgba');
```

Just make sure the background color isn't rgba already:

```
var bg = $(this).css('background-color');
if(bg.indexOf('a') == -1){
    var result = bg.replace(')', ', 0.75)').replace('rgb', 'rgba');
}
```

Comment: caution, if `this` has no background-color set, `css('background-color')` will return `undefined`.

Comment: I've added a jsperf test showing diff of using `replace` vs `substr` to achieve this.  `substr` is clearly the winner. https://jsperf.com/replace-rbg-with-rgba

Answer (score 5):

Another regex try http://jsfiddle.net/hc3BA/

```
var colour = 'rgb(123,123,123)',
new_col = colour.replace(/rgb/i, "rgba");
new_col = new_col.replace(/\)/i,',0.75)');
```

Comment: regexes are overkill if all you're doing is matching 1 exact string.

Comment: Suggestion, proof of concept, feel free to evolve the code.

Answer (score 2):

http://regex101.com/r/lT9iM4

```
var re = /(rgb)\(([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+)/; 
var currentColor = $(this).css('background-color');
var subst = 'rgba($2,$3,$4,0.75'; 

$(this).css('background-color', currentColor.replace(re, subst));
```

Another solution using regex. But as [Cerbrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) mentioned, using regex for something this simple is overkill.

Comment: `currentColor.replace(re, subst)` is returning something like this, for me: `"rgb(255, 255, 255)"`

Comment: `currentColor.replace(re, subst)` --> `"rgba(rgb,255,255,0.75)"`.

Regexes are just way overkill for something as simple as these 2 replacements.

Comment: Fixed subst too. Added note for overkill ;)