# text shadow same as font color with transparency

Tags: css

I have used many colors in my website and i want to apply **text-shadow** to all text but i want it with **transparency**

right now i using following code to do that

**Code :**

```
body{
    text-shadow: transparent 0 0 0, rgba(0,0,0, 0.75) 0 0 0.001px;
}
```

but it apply black color with transparency for example if color is red so i want text-shadow red with transparency.

any help would be appreciated.. thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write small jQuery function for my solution

```
$("p").each(function() {
    textShadow = $(this).css("color").replace(')', ', 0.75)').replace('rgb', 'rgba');
    $(this).css('text-shadow', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 0 0 0, ' + textShadow + ' 0 0 0.001px');
});
```

[Reference stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608856/convert-rgb-color-value-to-rgba-at-0-75-alpha)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way in pure CSS to have a color value that references existing color values with an arbitrary alpha value. The closest you can get is `currentColor` (which `text-shadow` already uses as the default color), but `currentColor` takes the existing alpha value as well and does not allow you to specify a custom alpha value.

You will need to specify the color values again in the text shadow, so if it's red:

```
text-shadow: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 0 0 0, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 0 0.001px;
```

(I avoided using the `transparent` keyword as some browsers are known to interpolate gradients incorrectly using `transparent`.)

Comment: I don't want it as cross-browser , i just want it for chrome , and i want only one css hack for this not for individual colors , look what you are trying that black color text has different css for text-shadow , red color has its different css , but i want same css for all colors across my website

Comment: Even notwithstanding the idea of developing exclusively for one browser, there's no way you can do this for just Chrome, because like I said, there's *no way* to do this. Take that as you will.

Comment: actually i'm using CSS hack @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {} for apply it only on webkit browser..

Answer (score 1):

Just don't specify any color:

```css
text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px;
```

Comment: This doesn't address the "with transparency" part. I want the same color as the text its shadowing but more transparent.